# driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)") not working in chrome driver

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I'm doing automation testing using Selenium Python. So I tried to navigate back to previous page and I've include this line of code in my script:

```
driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

But then it is not working, it didn't navigate back to previous page. This is my whole code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

#define variable driver
def func1():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/sabrina/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get("url")
    return driver

driver = func1()
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3)

#click email button
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
emailbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="q-app"]/div/div[2]/main/div/button[1]')
emailbutton.click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

#enter email & password
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="q-app"]/div/div[2]/main/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/input').send_keys("email")
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="q-app"]/div/div[2]/main/div/form/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/input').send_keys("password")
driver.implicitly_wait(50)

#assertion/checkpoint
element3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="q-app"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[3]').text
assert element3 == "Forgot your password?"

#click Login with Email button
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="q-app"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/button').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
element4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="q-app"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button').text
assert element4 == "MAKE REQUEST"

#click Messages
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="q-app"]/div/div[2]/header/div[1]/div/div/button[3]/div[2]').click()
time.sleep(2)

#choose requests with "Negotiation" status
element_negoreq = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="q-app"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]')
if (element_negoreq.text == "Negotiation"):
    element_negoreq.click()

    #click Book Now
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="q-app"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/button[2]').click()

    #tick Agree
    time.sleep(3)
    #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="q-app"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[11]/div/div/div[1]').click()

    #assert checkout word in current url
    assert "checkout" in driver.current_url
    print(driver.current_url)

    #click Boost
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="q-app"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[12]/div/button[1]').click()
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

All the codes before the navigate back script line are working until it reached the line. I also tried to use `driver.back()` but also not working. Is there anything to do with my indents or I don't include/import the related module? Anyone can advice?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting ?

Comment: No error message actually. It says "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: Okay , what is expected from click on you have written just before driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)") ? It is loading any new page ??

Comment: yes... it loads new page.

Comment: Please see answer section , as I could not put all information in one comment here , I have provided in answer section. I hope it will clear your doubts. Please let me know if it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

To simply go back to the previous url do these two things.

```
driver.back()
driver.refresh()
```

Comment: firstly i already add those two lines but it doesn't go to the current page. then i added time.sleep() before the two lines and it works already. thanks. but may i know why i cannot use driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)") ?

Comment: It may have not finished with whatever action it was doing.

Comment: Try using Webdriver wait to find elements and click them. Instead of various implicit waits and time.sleep().

Comment: cannot use implicit wait? why?

Comment: time.sleep(1)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
 You have some of these which kind of do the same.

Comment: Plus if it's just to wait for elements to load it's better to use explicit waits. It lowers the time to run the program.

Comment: i see.. thanks... so only need to use either one only not both in a script.. right?

Comment: suggest using driver.implicit wait

Answer (score 0):

As you have confirmed, after executing line

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="q-app"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[12]/div/button[1]').click()
```

A new page is loading. Since your page has not loaded completely and java scripts clicked back button, it was not effective. You can induce some sort of wait mechanism here to make sure page is loaded completely. Simplest thing would be to use time.sleep() but it’s not a good solution. Best solution I can think of is using explicit wait like below:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="q-app"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[12]/div/button[1]').click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '<xpath of any element on new page>'))) #It will insure page is loaded completely.
driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

Please try above code, it will navigate back as expected.

Comment: i already tried your code, but it don't navigate back to prev page as expected.